# Level truncation in String Field Theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, tachyon, string-field-theory

In string field theory, to study tachyon condensation at level-2, the string field is truncated to $$\Psi=t c_{1}|0\rangle+ u c_{-1}|0\rangle+ v L_{-2}^{(m)} c_{1}|0\rangle,$$  where $t,u, v$ are tachyonic degrees of freedom. The refernce in question is Eq. 3.9 in Analytic Methods in Open String Field Theory by Yuji Okawa. I wish to know how is this level truncation performed? How do you obtain the above equation?

Link to the reference is here https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/128/6/1001/2938823